# How much of differential geometry can be developed entirely without atlases?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

We may define a topological manifold to be a second-countable Hausdorff space such that every point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  We can further define a smooth manifold to be a topological manifold equipped with a structure sheaf of rings of smooth functions by transport of structure from $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a canonical sheaf of differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, with a canonical restriction sheaf to any open subset.    This gives a manifold as a locally ringed space. (Of course this definition generalizes to all sorts of other kinds of manifolds with minor adjustments).

Then the questions:
If we totally ignore the definition using atlases, will we at some point hit a wall? Can we fully develop differential geometry without ever resorting to atlases?

Regardless of the above answer, are there any books that develop differential geometry *primarily* from a "locally ringed space" viewpoint, dropping into the language of atlases only when necessary?  I looked at Kashiwara & Schapira's "Sheaves on Manifolds", but that's much more focused on sheaves of abelian groups and (co)homology.

Edit:

To clarify (Since Pete and Kevin misunderstood): It's easy to show that the approaches are equivalent, but proofs using charts don't *always* translate easily to proofs using sheaves.

Comment: Are you looking for some formal differential geometry? A.Rosenberg ever wrote some papers on this topic(but never published). He used noncommutative AG machine reconstruct the differential geometry. 

Comment: I am a Riemannian geometer, and I am curious what you are trying to accomplish. The basic reason why some differential geometry is done in coordinates is that using the correct coordinates adapted for the problem at hand makes computations much easier and gives invaluable insight like the Jordan normal form gives insight into matrices. Try computing curvature tensor of complex projective space without coordinates. I know only a few cases where sheaf theoretic language helps but the the most part I do not see why bother. It is more efficient to use other methods.    

Comment: @Igor: I prefer to leave computations as the "last step", so to speak.  That is, proofs should be coordinate free when possible.

Comment: It's like in linear algebra, where choosing coordinates can actually obscure the important points.

Comment: The classical point of view used neither atlases nor locally ringed spaces. Instead, it was all about submanifolds of $R^n$, defined by functions. (Admittedly, one does need to prove a condition on derivatives of the functions that's equivalent to the submanifold being locally diffeomorphim to $R^m$). Riemann and Gauss got quite far with it.

Comment: @Igor: I would agree that trying to study a Riemannian manifold via its sheaf of smooth functions has limited potential, but on the other hand, I do think a lot of Riemannian geometry is best done without co-ordinates. In co-ordinates, you have a lot of extra baggage that is a pain in the neck, including Christoffel symbols. As for your example of complex projective space, there are definitely clean and easy ways to compute its curvature without using co-ordinates.

Comment: It seems now that the question was supposed to be "How much of differential geometry can be done in a global, coordinate-free way?"  To me, this is significantly different from what was actually asked: atlases and LRSs use local coordinates in almost exactly the same way, I think.  Maybe a revised title/revised question/further question would be helpful.  

Comment: @Harry: there are many cases when working in coordinates makes things much easier; in other situations coordinate-free arguments work better. I think sticking to either approach will inevitably "obscure important points".  

Comment: @Deane, when I was talking of coordinates I meant the frame in which the computation is done, e.g. for the complex projective space the way the frame is chosen should reflect the fact how the space came about, say as the base of a Riemannian submersion from a sphere. But you are right, there are other ways of doing this; I just do not find them easier.

Comment: @Deane, @Igor: There is another approach that many geometers feel is as intrinsic as the "coordinate-free" approach and  often makes calculations even more revealing and easier than "choosing well-adapted coordinates". I mean the "moving frame" approach, going back to Elie Cartan, and the favored method of Chern and his students. The point is that there is very frequently an absolutely natural choice of moving frame in a given situation (for example, for a manifold embedded in Euclidean space there is the principal curvature framing) and working in this makes many computations much clearer.

Comment: This may be nitpicking, but OP's definition of a smooth manifold is actually inaccurate. The local homeomorphisms with $\mathbb{R}^n$ are part of the structure of a manifold, it's not enough just to require their existence. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to know how to pull the differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ back to the manifold. (Remember there's more than one differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.) So the atlas is already non-avoidable in the definition!

Comment: Alain Connes has shown, that you can encode the structure of a Riemannian manifold in a spectral triple. You should think about it as an analogue of Gelfand-Naimark for topological spaces.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53021/defining-a-manifold-without-reference-to-the-reals

Comment: I see 3 reopen votes, but no related (or any other recent) comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is the book by Ramanan "Global Calculus" which develops differential geometry relying heavily on sheaf theory (you should see his definition of connection algebra...).
He avoids the magic words "locally ringed space" by requiring the structure sheaf to be a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions (hence maximal ideal of stalks = vanishing functions).

Comment: This book looks really good!

Comment: i currently have this book checked out from my library. havent spent enough time with it though.

Comment: A nitpick: It is not true that every subsheaf of rings of the sheaf of continuous functions gives a locally ringed space. For example, take the real line (with its standard topology) and let $\mathcal{O}(U)$ be the functions on $U$ which, on each connected component of $U$, are restrictions of polynomials. Then the stalk at any point is $\mathbb{R}[x]$, which is not a local ring. However, it is true that each stalk contains a canonical maximal ideal, of the functions which vanish at that point. This may be enough for many purposes.

Answer (score 27):

This is a comment, not an answer, but is too long to fit in the comment box: having read the question, answers, and comments, I don't quite follow the intent of this question:

We can define a manifold to be a locally ringed space in which each point has a neighbourhood
isomorphic to an open subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ (or even just ${\mathbb R}^n$ itself) with its sheaf of smooth functions (plus second countability and  Hausdorffness, if you like).    As was remarked by Dmitri, the collection of all such will then form an atlas, but one doesn't need to say this.

As Pete Clark says, what I've said so far is evident.

But it seems that another aspect of the question is whether one can always avoid working in coordinates.  This seems to have nothing to do with atlases.

E.g. in arguments in the locally ringed space set-up, one will certainly in many instances verify that a property can be checked locally, and then verify it on Euclidean space with
its natural smooth structure.  (Just as in the theory of schemes, one often shows that a property is local, and then checks it in the affine case.)

Now one can ask: can one avoid the latter kinds of arguments?  This seems unlikely: manifolds are *defined* to be locally Euclidean (no matter which of the possible formalisms one is using), and so if one is proving theorems about manifolds, one will
have to use this somewhere.  For example, one can surely define the tangent sheaf in
a coordiante free way, but to prove that it is locally free of rank equal to the dimension
of the manifold, one is going to reduce to a local computation and then appeal to calculus
on Euclidean spaces; there is no other way!

[EDIT: The last sentence may be too categorical of a declaration; see Dmitri Pavlov's answer for a suggestion of a more substantially algebraic reformulation of the
notion of manifold.]

Comment: We can't reduce it to commutative algebra by using the module of kahler differentials?

Comment: Then invoke smoothness to sho that the dimension works out alright?

Comment: "Invoking smoothness" means "doing calculus locally on Euclidean space".   Somewhere, there is a property of smooth functions on Euclidean space that you are going to have to use, that will be a matter of calculus.  It is certainly possible to develop the foundations in a more coordinate-free way than most texts; the first of Spivak's five volumes is good for this (since he goes carefully over all the possible approaches to the various definitions).   But the local Euclidean nature of manifolds is intrinsic to the definition, and will always have to be used somewhere in some way.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  There's no purely algebraic way to deal with things on the local level?

Comment: @Emerton: I'm not sure I understand your point. Although the calculus of Euclidean space is most easily proved using the standard co-ordinates, all of the theorems can be stated without any reference to co-ordinates. So just because you're using calculus to prove something does not mean you have to use local co-ordinates. Also, it is in fact possible to prove many (maybe all) calculus theorems using the vector space and topological structures of Euclidean space without using co-ordinates.

Comment: @Harry: What does "purely algebraic" mean? The local topological structure of Euclidean space is quite crucial in differential geometry.

Comment: Dear Deane, 

I just mean that at some point you have to refer back to Euclidean space and use its analytic properties in some way.  I agree that it is a fairly tautological point.  I was just trying to get my mind around what was behind the objection to atlases (which for me just evokes a collection of Euclidean opens covering the manifold), and pointing out that somewhere you have to exploit the locally Euclidean nature of the situation.  

Comment: How do you know that there is no other way?
I mentioned in my answer that “One might hope that these additional conditions can be formulated in terms of dimensions of some vector bundles constructed from this algebra (e.g., tangent bundle, jet bundle, connections etc.).”.

In other words, the fact that the tangent bundle is locally free of rank equal to the dimension of the manifold might very well become a part of a new definition of a manifold.

Comment: Dear Dmitri,

Thanks for your remark, which shows that I didn't pay sufficient attention to your answer.  I am editing my answer in what I hope is an appropriate manner.

Comment: @Harry: The algebraically defined sheaf of modules of Kaehler differentials does (of the sheaf of smooth functions over the sheaf of locally constant functions) does *not* coincide with the usual sheaf of differential forms as considered in differential geometry. Only its double dual does. (Unraveling the definitions, this is mostly a triviality.)

Answer (score 15):

I would say that it is *a priori* clear that ALL of differential geometry (and differential topology, complex geometry, etc.) can be developed using the language of locally ringed spaces rather than atlases.

"Atlas" was never an important technique in the subject; it is just a definition, a sort of reification of the idea that there is some specific "structure" which corresponds to the ability to tell when a function on an abstract manifold is smooth or not.  But the main idea has never been anything other than the following simple one: for a function to be smooth, it has to be compatible with each of the coordinate charts (i.e., a differentiability condition on the composite maps) which also have to be compatible with each other and cover the manifold in question.  [And one easily generalizes from smooth functions on a smooth manifold to smooth maps between smooth manifolds.]

The awkward part of the definition of atlas comes when we depart from the simple (and obviously necessary) conditions above and say "Now an **atlas** is a *maximal* set of such charts [or possibly an equivalence class of sets of charts]".  This part of the definition has been explicitly made fun of by Gian-Carlo Rota in his [I believe; I haven't gone back to check this point] *Indiscrete Thoughts*, in which he refers to the concept as a "polite fiction".

Anyway, the point is that you want to be able to say what a smooth map between manifolds is.  If we agree on what such maps are, then we are talking about the same concrete category of manifolds and smooth maps.  You can certainly check that the notion of LRS gives rise to the same category -- but via a formalism which you, I and much of the contemporary mathematical world probably views as more graceful than that of atlases -- and that's really all that matters.

Comment: That's what I'd hoped to hear.  The question is: things like the inverse function theorem seem like they're more easily stated using atlases (at least I don't know of a good statement using locally ringed spaces).  I'd like to see all of the common theorems stated in terms of LRS's, whence came the book request.

Comment: I actually don't see how atlases come up in the statement of the inverse function theorem [or even what this result has to do with manifolds at all, really; you can apply it to maps between manifolds, but by nature it's a local result].  Do you have a specific formulation or reference in mind?

Comment: Well, a few days ago in my differential geometry class, a proof was given of some fact (I think it was called the "local form of an immersion" in book I of spivak).  I asked the professor if there was an analogue of the proof stated in terms of locally ringed spaces, and he said that the proof relied on the IFT, so there was no natural way to phrase it in terms of LRSpaces.  This question was kinda of a "half-question" and "half-reference-request"

Comment: Hmm.  I think I would rather say that the proof would be word for word identical in the language of LRS [except for removing all instances of "atlas" from the proof; I would be mildly surprised to find any].  But I'm not teaching the class and I don't want to contradict the professor, who I'm sure knows what he is doing.  

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure he knows what he's doing too.  This is not some attempt to "prove him wrong", but rather to find a reference that discusses all of this in a more palatable way for me, at least.  

Comment: This reminded me of the message that I try to get across in my "comparative smootheology" talks (that's _talks_, not article): that the point (ha ha) of smooth manifolds is to define what "smooth map" means and for _that_ we only need to agree on what smooth curves are - the whole "atlas" and "chart" stuff is just to ensure that we agree on this.  Interestingly, if you read Kriegl and Michor's book then you get the impression that they regard IFT as being what separates "hard" and "soft" geometry (my words).

Comment: Andrew, I have to agree with you. What's the point of doing differential geometry without a being able to do analysis on them? I enjoy synthetic reasoning, but when looking at how far they got, I'd rather rely on a theory with an inverse function theorem. (Anyone ever thought about sheaves with values in Hilbert/Banach manifolds?)

Comment: I don't really follow the debate going on here. So what if a few key tools such as the IFT need to be proved using local co-ordinates. Once you have it, it can be stated and used in a co-ordinate-free environment. Virtually all of PDE theory is proved using local or global co-ordinates, but once you have developed the necessary tools and restated the theorems in a co-ordinate-free form, you can often successfully avoid co-ordinates when applying the PDE theorems to differential geometry.

Comment: @orby: this is a question i might well have asked. I understand that hard analysis is important, but i am not a hard analyst and i would still like to have some understanding. For myself at least, things like vector bundles are easier for me to understand than some relation between christoffel symbols, its just the way i think. I am particularly interested in things that deane seems to be alluding to above, global geometric type results from PDE!

Answer (score 15):

Your definition of a smooth manifold still uses atlases in a slightly
disguised way because it amounts to saying that a smooth manifold is a topological manifold with an open  cover whose elements are equipped with an isomorphism of the restriction of the structure sheaf
and the standard sheaf on R^n.  This open cover is nothing else but an atlas.

Thus one still needs an atlas-free definition of a smooth manifold.
One possible way to do this is to define the category of smooth manifolds
as the opposite category of the full subcategory of the category of real algebras consisting of real algebras
satisfying certain properties, e.g., the intersection of kernels of all homomorphisms to R must be 0.
One might hope that these additional conditions can be formulated in terms of dimensions
of some vector bundles constructed from this algebra (e.g., tangent bundle, jet bundle, connections etc.).

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing something like this.

Comment: If you have a look at Toen's notes (a masters course on stacks) he recovers the definition of manifold just as a particular sheaf on the site consisting of open subsets of euclidean spaces (with smooth maps between them) and coverings being jointly surjective families of open immersions.
It's all part of a general theory of "Geometric Contexts" (although theory is probably a too big a name). In the same vein he recovers schemes from affine schemes (of course!).

Comment: Neat.  I haven't given it a full read yet, but it is my intention to.

Comment: I have to add a thought I had a few days ago. A lot of physics has to be coordinate-independent. Classically, this is interpreted as it should not matter which chart you chose. But you could also state it this way: It does not matter that you choose a chart at all!! In principle any other reasonable method of local description should be taken into account, too. Maybe I read to much synthetic stuff, lately...

Comment: "Thus one still needs an atlas-free definition of a smooth manifold."  Why? Not "Why are locally ringed spaces not truly atlas-free?" I understand that and that was essentially my response, but why would be it be desirable to speak of manifolds in a way that avoids mentioning that they are locally isomorphic to Euclidean space?  What does one hope to gain by doing so?  Anything in manifold theory itself?

Comment: @Pete: I hope to obtain a better exposition of the theory of smooth manifolds,
closer in style to algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Pete: I am personally interested in singular spaces, in particular when "usual" coordinate descriptions break down. One then needs more local models (I personally disagree with doing manifolds scheme-style).

Comment: @Dmitri I think a lot of the most important analytic properties of smooth manifolds-particularly those that arise in geometric analysis-would suffer from such a treatment. And we won't even bring up the crucial applications of manifold theory to modern physics,which are legion. I think it can be done,I just think it's going to cause more headaches then it would solve.

Comment: @Andrew L: Do you have any concrete examples of properties of smooth manifolds that would suffer from such a treatment?  By the way, when applications of smooth manifolds to physics are expressed in coordinate-free form, they become more easy to understand.

Comment: @Dmitri: algebraic methods do not suffice to develop the smooth theories, one needs differential calculus. The reason is that the algebra of smooth functions has poor ring-theoretic properties (it is not noetherian, ideals do not correspond to submanifolds). 

Comment: Whether one should always pick and NAME a SPECIFIC coordinate system is a completely different question and I fully agree that one should avoid choices of coordinates if possible.

Comment: @Johannes: One can do differential calculus using algebraic methods.  Noncommutative geometry is an example.

Answer (score 14):

This matter is discussed in Tennison's "sheaf theory". He defines manifolds your way and writes (p. 90):
"...the above definition is in accordance with the more usual definitions in terms of atlases of charts with transition maps of the appropriate kind[...], with two possible exceptions. Some authors may require that $X$ have a countable basis of open sets. Other authors may insist that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X )$ satisfy a separation (hausdorff) condition..."
You might also be interested in the treatment "Smooth Manifolds and Observables" by Jet Nestruev, where manifolds are characterised by their ring of smooth functions (it has to be "geometric").
Last but not least you might take a look at "Algebraic Geometry over C-infinity rings" by Dominic Joyce,
http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0023
where "classical" differential geometry is widely generalised (in the sense of Spivak's derived manifolds).

Comment: Let me just point out that the "exceptions" referred to above have nothing to do with charts (which are local in nature), but only give restrictions on the underlying topological space.  In particular, the question of whether one wants manifolds to be second countable and/or Hausdorff comes up in just the same way in the classical formulation as well.  (I guess the point of the remark is that it is less "classical" not to require these conditions as a part of the definition.)

Answer (score 12):

Apart from Nestruev's book which is good but unfortunately very elementary,
I recommend you to take a look at Ramanan's Global Calculus.
Ramanan almost manages to avoid coordinates except for a few places and yet is able to prove nontrivial theorems.

Answer (score 10):

It is an easy exercise to show that the standard definition of a manifold is equivalent to the ringed spaces definition of a manifold. (Try it!)

The latter definition is nice because the sheaf condition gets rid of the need for all that "maximal atlas" business.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at in my answer.  +1 for your exhortation "Try it!" which would be my advice as well.

Comment: I've put an explanation in the OP.  Proving equivalence is pretty straightforward.  The problem is, sometimes proving something about a mathematical object is easier in one formalism than another one.  For example, the functor of points approach to algebraic geometry allows us to get lots of proofs for free, but some proofs are still easier using locally ringed spaces (consider the algebraic and analytic structures of a complex variety).

Comment: And of course I've "tried it!"  it was on homework 2 or 3.

Comment: Rather, the analytic structure associated with the variety.

Comment: Well, you don't really remove the maximal atlas, you just hide it in another box. It's fairly impossible to check whether an atlas is maximal, that's obviously true. But on the other hand - do you know all open sets of R^n, together with all smooth functions on them? In practice you are dealing with an open cover only (Cech-style). The same is true for atlases!

Answer (score 10):

There is another way to develop differential geometry without atlases, and even without charts, that is [*Diffeology*](http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/Site/The%20Book/The%20Book.html). I'm not sure this is the right answer to your question but it worths looking at.

**Comment**: There are many ways to develop differential geometry without atlases. You may change the category of differentiable manifolds for a larger one. This is the case for Diffeology, or Differential Spaces à la Sikorski. These two approaches correspond to the two ways you may interpret the smooth structure: in the first case the smooth structure is characterized by the smooth parametrizations in the space (called plots), this is the "in-way", in the second case the smooth structure is characterized by the smooth functions from the space into the field of real numbers $\bf R$, the "out-way". In some sense they are "dual" but not equivalent approaches. The "intersection" of these two approches gives the so-called Frölicher spaces (reflexive diffeological spaces). The diffeological way gives a richer category than the Sikorski's one. For example it gives a non trivial structure for quotients (like spaces of leaves of a dense foliation, for example) where Sikorski structure is trivial. The two of them gives access to infinite dimensional spaces, without necessarily modeling these spaces on topological vector spaces. You can develop a whole theory of homotopy, cohomology, differential calculus and De-Rham cohomology, groups, fiber bundles etc. in diffeology without loosing much of what you have learned in manifold differential geometry.

Well, there is a lot say, may be too much for this discussion :-)

Comment: By the way, this is related to the definition mentioned above, as appearing for instance in Toen's master course notes on algebraic stacks: a diffeological space is a concrete sheaf on the category of smooth open balls, and a smooth manifold is a locally representable such sheaf. 

Comment: Hey Urs, yes sure! However, I must admit that my intuition in diffeology never came from the formal categorical properties, even if I never ignored this point of view, but it came from my familiarity with ordinary differential geometry (for example, when I had to define what is a diffeological fiber bundle to include any quotient of kind $G/H$). I tried stay the closest as possible to the classical vocabulary, just to spare my energy and focus on the geometrical intuition. But I agree, times changing :)

Comment: Yesm sure. It just occurred to me that all these commenters here are happily chatting about smooth analogs of algebraic stacks, but not so much about your diffeology. Which is kind of curious, because its two ways to talk about the same thing, essentially.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called *abstract differential geometry* "developed" by Mallios et al ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_differential_geometry)). Perhaps you should skim through the first chapter of his book "Modern Differential Geometry in Gauge Theories: Maxwell fields". It looks pretty nice (despite the physical title). But I don't know how readable or how awesome all this is, I did not read it (there are too many nice explicit things to figure out...).

Comment: I'm sceptic about Mallios' generalization, in particular since he claims to do "physics"...

Comment: Nah, I did not have the impression that the first(!) chapter has been written by a "physicist". I think most of the stuff has also been discussed in "Geometry of vector sheaves: an axiomatic approach to differential geometry" by Mallios and this is entirely mathematics...

Answer (score 1):

Just as everyone else is saying, I don't think we really gain anything (at least if we stick to just studying differential and Riemannian manifolds). In essence, both approaches tell us exactly what the smooth functions on our manifold look like, and differential geometry is mainly concerned with the (analytic) behavior of these functions on our manifold and what they tell us about the manifold.

For example, if one wants to know that geodesics exist, or that parallel vector fields exist, the problem reduces to one of finding unique solutions of differential equations locally (and then using the uniqueness to patch everything together). I don't see an advantage of one side over the other *when developing the theory.*

On the other hand, there may be more advanced topics which would be better looked at from a sheaf theoretic viewpoint, but I can't say much about this.

Answer (score 1):

Take also a look at "Theory of Lie Groups I" by C. Chevalley (Princeton UP 1946), chapter III. That approach (differential structure defined by choosing a ring of functions) is further developed in R. Penrose & W. Rindler, "Spinors and Space-Time 1" (Cambridge UP 1984), section 4.1 ff.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on a similar quest and have a tentative answer (I'm currently working it out). My definition of a generalized differential manifold would be: A locally ringed space with nontrivial cotangent sheaf. Covariant derivatives can be defined using only the cotangent sheaf, and there is a dual version of the fundamental lemma of Riemannian geometry for this. (My creed: forget tangent space.)

The abstract differential geometry of Mallios et al looks quite attractive to me, but I haven't yet read it in detail (lacking time, money, and a useable math library). One immediate problem I see with their definition of vector bundle, being the usual suspect, a locally finite and free sheaf module. But a major motivation for using sheaves is infinite dimensional applications, like path space (I suspect path space should be introduced before geodesics, Jacobi fields, General Relativity, perhaps Brownian motion... Dunno how sheaves connect to uniform spaces...).

I have an incomplete copy of yummy lectures by Jürgen Bingener, Regensburg 1983/4 on basics of calculus and Riemannian geometry in the language of ringed spaces. Need to contact him and ask for more.

Comment: Di you get the notes about ringed spaces?