# Why "smooth Gelfand duality" does not involve a topology on the algebras?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The following question naturally originates from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21168/how-to-classify-the-algebras-cm)
and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21090/smooth-gelfand-duality).

While the usual $C^{0}$ Gelfand duality involves a topology on the function algebras considered (it relates compact Hausdorff topological spaces to unital $C^{*}$-algebras, which in particular are Banach algebras), why the "smooth Gelfand duality" seems, according to what I understood from the above questions, to see *only* the "pure" algebraic structure of certain algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

**Edit:** I've just read the introduction of [this](http://books.google.it/books?id=79bCwXbVnHAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=C-infinity+differentiable+spaces&source=bl&ots=xjtnnn8bSq&sig=BnSizsqq1t7wT8deQfeE--Ts4Ps&hl=it&ei=8w_DS92DFo7U7APZiu2tCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). The topology actually enters the picture, but not in the form of a structure of topological algebra on the function spaces that locally model those $C^{\infty}$-differentiable spaces; it enters the picture when [defining](http://books.google.it/books?id=79bCwXbVnHAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=C-infinity+differentiable+spaces&source=bl&ots=xjtnnn8bSq&sig=BnSizsqq1t7wT8deQfeE--Ts4Ps&hl=it&ei=8w_DS92DFo7U7APZiu2tCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) a "differentiable algebra" as the quotient of the algebra of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a *Fréchet-closed* ideal.

But a question still stands: would it be possible to define compact Hausdorff topological spaces in the analogous way? 
Perhaps the answer is "no because of a lack of a universal local model $C^{0}(...)$", but "yes in the case of topological *manifolds*". 
Does it make sense?

Comment: In the case of Gelfand duality, one also does not need topology in the following sense: all the maximal ideals are closed, and they all give points of the corresponding topological space.  So is the situation really so different? 

Comment: Well, technically a $C^{*}$-algebra is, in particular, a *topological* algebra, while the $\mathbb{R}$-algebras that are local models for C-infty differentiable spaces are just algebras with no further structure. Or maybe we can consider the latter as endowed with a topology induced by the Fréchet topology on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?...

Comment: Well a C*-algebra is, in a sense, just an algebra. That is, a *-algebra on which A->sqrt(spectral radius of A* A) is a complete Banach-algebra norm.

Comment: @Emerton: but in order to recover the Gelfand topology on the maximal ideal space of a Banach algebra, doesn't the topology of the algebra enter here? or am I misunderstanding your point.

Comment: @yenon: the topology is not involved (but useful for arguments).

Comment: @Martin: Now I am definitely confused, and curious. Are we still talking about the Gelfand representation for commutative Banach algebras (with identity element, say)? How are you going to define the Gelfand topology on the maximal ideal space, without using the continuous dual linear space of the original algebra? 

Comment: @Martin: oh, wait, if we're taking about commutative C*-algebras then I guess you could take the hull-kernel topology on the maximal ideal space. Is that (similar to) what you meant?

Comment: let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. then $Spec(A)$ is defined to be the set of $C^*$-homomorphisms $A \to \mathbb{C}$. It is endowed with the final topology with respect to all $Spec(A) \to \mathbb{C}, p \mapsto p(f)$, where $f$ runs through $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need a topology because the proofs show that the space can be recovered without a topology. I think it's just that simple. Perhaps this is not satisfactory for you?

Continuing George's comment, there is an important result in the theory of $C^\*$-algebras: the norm is unique. The reason is that every $C^\*$-homomorphism is of norm $\leq 1$. In particular, the category of $C^\*$-algebras is a full subcategory of the category of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with involution and basically I could also ask for a pure algebraic characterization of the essential image... In particular, the category of compact hausdorff spaces is a full subcategory of the opposite category of commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with involution. Thus we have the same situation as in the smooth Gelfand duality.

Comment: I see         .